# why Service worker is slow?

Tags: service-worker, nuxt.js

I am developing a project with `nuxt`. I installed `Service Worker` to this project using [this](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/) package. The `nuxt.config.js` file is like this:

```
export default {
    mode: 'universal',

    /*
    ** Headers of the page
    */
    head: {
    title: 'my_project',
    meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
    },

    /*
    ** Customize the progress-bar color
    */
    loading: { color: '#fff' },

    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    css: [
        '~/static/css/base.css',
        '~/static/css/hooper.css',
        '~/static/css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css',
    ],

    /*
    ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
    */
    plugins: [
      { src: '~plugins/ga.js', ssr: false }
    ],

    /*
    ** Nuxt.js modules
    */
    modules: [
        // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        '@nuxtjs/device',
    ],

    manifest:{
        "short_name": "my_project",
        "name": "my_project",
        "icons": [
            {
                "src": "/static/icon.png",
                "type": "image/png",
            },
        ],
        "start_url": "/",
        "background_color": "white",
        "display": "standalone",
        "scope": "/",
        "theme_color": "white"
    },

    workbox:{

    },


    /*
    ** Axios module configuration
    */
    axios: {
        // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
    },

    /*
    ** Build configuration
    */
    build: {
        /*
        ** You can extend webpack config here
        */
        extend(config, ctx) {
        }
    },

    hooks:{
        // This hook is called before generatic static html files for SPA mode
        'generate:page': (page) => {
            if(page.path.includes('/amp/')){
                page.html = modify_html(page.html)
            }
        },
        // This hook is called before rendering the html to the browser
        'render:route': (url, page, { req, res }) => {
            if(url.includes('/amp/')){
                page.html = modify_html(page.html)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But `Service Worker` is so slow. for example:

[image: normal query to the server before service worker]

[image: query to the service worker]

In this example normal query to the server takes 1.43 seconds and `Service Worker` query takes 1.37 seconds. How can i make `Service Worker` faster?

Comment: [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) is not a service worker being slow but your server to return a response (first byte of the response to be precise). Eg: create a php script which will: 1) sleep for 10 seconds 2) echo '1' - the TTFB will be 10 seconds. Fix your backend!

Comment: you mean it does not use service worker?

Comment: @hamid In the screenshot your provided, there are two calls to `search?query=chera`. One of them is time spent in the service worker and the other is the actual fetch initiated by the service worker. It is not the service worker that is taking all that time but instead the actual fetch to your back end.

Comment: @JustinCollins sorry i did not understand. You mean frontend sends a request to the service worker then service worker sends the request to the backend?

Comment: @hamid Exactly. The network tab shows both the request as it enters the service worker and the subsequent request as it goes the server.